# Notepad++ regex for unix epoch timestamp

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that has unix epoch timestamps mixed in with a lot of scrambled text. So, I need to check for 10 digit numbers, starting and ending with non-numeric characters.

I tried:

```
[:alpha:]([0-9]{10})[:alpha:]
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think it should be `[[:alpha:]]([0-9]{10})[[:alpha:]]` See https://regex101.com/r/2KAGns/1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the POSIX [:alpha:] doesn't work with Notepad++

`[:alpha:]` equals `[a-zA-Z]` and in your case may also be substituted by `\D` *(equals One non-digit)*

Have you tried one of these:

*(fist will select 10 digits including 2 extra characters at start/end 
 others with lookahead/lookbehind just select the exact 10 digits)*

- `\D([0-9]{10})\D`
- `(?<=\D)([0-9]{10})(?=\D)`    *positive lookahead/lookbehind*
- `(?<!\d)([0-9]{10})(?!\d)`    *negative lookahead/lookbehind*

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this text with notepad++:

```
aaa1234567890bbb
11.1234567890@99
too short:123456789
```

- search: `(?<=\D)(\d{10})(?=\D)`
- replace: (whatever you want; use $1 for captured number)

Explanation:

- `(?<=\D)` - positive lookbehind for a non-digit char (no capture)
- `(\d{10})` - capture 10 digits
- `(?=\D)` - positive lookahead for a non-digit char (no capture)

Comment: `[^\d]` is equal to `\D`